# Issues deploying Self-Hosted Agent on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) Container

Tags: docker, azure-devops, containers

To begin, I followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops) in order to deploy a self-hosted agent on a linux container. I didn't do anything other than create the Dockerfile as start.sh file as it stated (copy and paste) to confirm I will add the files here:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# To make it easier for build and release pipelines to run apt-get,
# configure apt to not require confirmation (assume the -y argument by default)
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes \"true\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90assumeyes

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        jq \
        git \
        iputils-ping \
        libcurl4 \
        libicu60 \
        libunwind8 \
        netcat \
        libssl1.0

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh

CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

**Start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ -z "$AZP_URL" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "error: missing AZP_URL environment variable"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$AZP_TOKEN_FILE" ]; then
  if [ -z "$AZP_TOKEN" ]; then
    echo 1>&2 "error: missing AZP_TOKEN environment variable"
    exit 1
  fi

  AZP_TOKEN_FILE=/azp/.token
  echo -n $AZP_TOKEN > "$AZP_TOKEN_FILE"
fi

unset AZP_TOKEN

if [ -n "$AZP_WORK" ]; then
  mkdir -p "$AZP_WORK"
fi

rm -rf /azp/agent
mkdir /azp/agent
cd /azp/agent

export AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"

cleanup() {
  if [ -e config.sh ]; then
    print_header "Cleanup. Removing Azure Pipelines agent..."

    ./config.sh remove --unattended \
      --auth PAT \
      --token $(cat "$AZP_TOKEN_FILE")
  fi
}

print_header() {
  lightcyan='\033[1;36m'
  nocolor='\033[0m'
  echo -e "${lightcyan}$1${nocolor}"
}

# Let the agent ignore the token env variables
export VSO_AGENT_IGNORE=AZP_TOKEN,AZP_TOKEN_FILE

print_header "1. Determining matching Azure Pipelines agent..."

AZP_AGENT_RESPONSE=$(curl -LsS \
  -u user:$(cat "$AZP_TOKEN_FILE") \
  -H 'Accept:application/json;api-version=3.0-preview' \
  "$AZP_URL/_apis/distributedtask/packages/agent?platform=linux-x64")

if echo "$AZP_AGENT_RESPONSE" | jq . >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  AZP_AGENTPACKAGE_URL=$(echo "$AZP_AGENT_RESPONSE" \
    | jq -r '.value | map([.version.major,.version.minor,.version.patch,.downloadUrl]) | sort | .[length-1] | .[3]')
fi

if [ -z "$AZP_AGENTPACKAGE_URL" -o "$AZP_AGENTPACKAGE_URL" == "null" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "error: could not determine a matching Azure Pipelines agent - check that account '$AZP_URL' is correct and the token is valid for that account"
  exit 1
fi

print_header "2. Downloading and installing Azure Pipelines agent..."

curl -LsS $AZP_AGENTPACKAGE_URL | tar -xz & wait $!

source ./env.sh

print_header "3. Configuring Azure Pipelines agent..."

./config.sh --unattended \
  --agent "${AZP_AGENT_NAME:-$(hostname)}" \
  --url "$AZP_URL" \
  --auth PAT \
  --token $(cat "$AZP_TOKEN_FILE") \
  --pool "${AZP_POOL:-Default}" \
  --work "${AZP_WORK:-_work}" \
  --replace \
  --acceptTeeEula & wait $!

print_header "4. Running Azure Pipelines agent..."

trap 'cleanup; exit 130' INT
trap 'cleanup; exit 143' TERM

# To be aware of TERM and INT signals call run.sh
# Running it with the --once flag at the end will shut down the agent after the build is executed
./run.sh & wait $!
```

Despite copy and pasting these from the documentation. I receive an error when it reaches the 3rd step (*Configuring Azure Pipelines Agent*) in the start.sh script.

Error message: **qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory**

If it helps, I am running docker on MacOS but as you can see the container is Ubuntu.

Thank you

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops), we can know Both Windows and Linux are supported as container hosts. But the MacOS is not support as container hosts. So you can try to create a new Windows docker container to try again.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, perhaps I overlooked this or thought it was stating that only window and linux containers were supported compared to it referring to what OS is hosting the containers. Will mark this as the correct answer and move forward with a Linux VM.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.